# C# Gecko web browser show then quit after 10 seconds

Tags: gecko

I have a problem when coding C# with Web Browser use Gecko library.

My code here:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Application.StartupPath + "\\xulrunner");

    string link = "http://google.com/";
    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(link);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

I want to when run my application, its will show my web browser with Google content and then automatic exit after 10 seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look your example, you have a very fast pc and when run app;

1- InitializeComponent 1 ms passed

2- Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize 1 ms passed

3- string link 1 ms passed

4- geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(link) 1 ms passed (but maybe page load 20.000 ms)

5- Thread.Sleep(10000); 10.000 ms sleep
and exit.

Now you should Document complete event and maybe usable timer, because all when thread sleep is your solution won't work.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Application.StartupPath + "\\xulrunner");

    string link = "http://google.com/";
    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(link);
    geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}



private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.start();
}
```

Last one, count with timer, and application.exit.